# Error loading extensions from online gallery menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, httprequest, firewall, visual-studio-extensions

I get the below error from the visualstudiogallery service when I try to load `Online` extensions from the VS2012 `Extensions and Updates`->Online menu:

[image]

What could be the possible reason and how can I rectify it to download extensions from the VS2012 menu?

Comment: Could VS be blocked by your firewall? It doesn't seem to be an actual server issue, I can access it.

Comment: @Lennart I can see VS2012 Update 1 ready to download in the updates section of menu and I did update it. But may be it can be a firewall issue..

Comment: Do you have some sort of proxy on your network?

Comment: I can download evry kind of updates from VS2012 as you can see in the screenshot in my ques. there is 1 update  in `Updates` section..